# Why is California's income filing threshold GREATER than the standard deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, california, state-income-tax

For California, [the tax instruction booklet](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2018/18-540-booklet.shtml) says that you need to file the income tax forms if your income is over $17,693 "gross" or $14,154 "adjusted".

However, the state's standard deduction is only $4,401!

So this leads to a seemingly **bizarre** situation that if your income is, say, $10,000, you have a tax liability, but don't actually have to file a return.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting the exemption credits. An adjusted gross income of $14,154, subtracting the standard deduction of $4,401, leaves a $9,753 taxable income, which for the Single filing status results in a tax of $111 (from the Form 540 tax table). Then you subtract the $118 exemption tax credit for Single with no dependents, and you have 0 tax.